# IOS Fan style carousel

Tags: ios, carousel

I'm building an IOS app using iCarousel ( http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel )

I want to transform the carousel in order to have it lookin like a "FAN". so, all the cards will be joined in one ponit at the top and you can scroll the cards.

My client get the idea from Drinkspiration of Absolut:

[image: Drinkspiration screenshot]
<sub>(source: [blogcdn.com](https://www.blogcdn.com/www.tuaw.com/media/2009/07/drinkspiration-location1.jpg))</sub>

How can I change the carousel in order to have this "effect"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    CGFloat radius = 400.0f;
    CGFloat angle = 0.5f; // in radians

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, -radius, 0.0f);
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -angle * offset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, radius, 0.0f);
}
```

The radius and angle are optimised for the example app included with iCarousel, so you'll need to tweak them for your app. You'll also need to return a numberOfVisibleItems of 3 or the views will wrap round and overlap themselves if there are too many in the carousel.

UPDATE:

This type of carousel is now built-in to the iCarousel library. Just use iCarouselTypeWheel.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone who finds this answer, this style is now included in the core library as iCarouselTypeWheel.

Comment: cool that's really interesting for a lot of people, great work!